# How to remove value from datagridview cell on cell click?

Tags: c#-4.0, datagridview

I have a datagridview column which value is showing 0.00 when form load which is a decimal value. I want to clear this column cell value when I click on particular cell and when I leave the cell the value(0.00) should come in the cell. I am attaching a snap shot for better understanding.

[image]

I want this on particular cell click. Is it possible with decimal values? How can I set a cell as empty? I have done some code on cell click but no result.

```
  private void dgvForecast_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
            {
                var cell = dgvForecast.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style as DataGridViewCellStyle;
                decimal val = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvForecast.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
                cell.Format = "";
                dgvForecast.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = val.ToString("#");
                cell.ApplyStyle(cell);
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

for deleting the cell value you can use

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
        {
            dataGridVirtuals[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = "";
        }
```

for putting up a value into the cell that loses focus you can use CellLeave event
eg

```
if(e.ColumnIndex==3)
{
dataGridView[e.ColumnIndex,e.RowIndex].Value=[yourvalue];

}
```

Comment: try parsing the field as DataGridViewTextBoxCell because i tried on my machine and its working.. your cell is textbox right?

Comment: yes my cell is textboxcell but the value which is bind with datasource     is double datatype.

Comment: oh if it is bounded with some data source then you can't just directly change the value. first clear your datasource and then bind it again

Comment: eg. suppose ur datasource is List<double> then create a new list as List<double> list=new List<double>(); and then cell.datasource=list;